# Laravel 5.5 render a React component in a blade view with data from the controller

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, laravel-5

My goals is to be able to do something like this in my blade view.

```
<Example name="{{ $user->name }}" />
```

But this doesn't render anything.

When I do: `<div id="example"></div>`it renders the component without the props value which is normal.

So I am trying to pass data that came from my controller to my React component as a prop.

I am not sure if it's even possible.

This is my App.js:

```
require('./components/Example');
```

This is my Example.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Example extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <div className="panel panel-default">
                            <div className="panel-heading">Example</div>

                            <div className="panel-body">
                                Hello, {this.props.name}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I do it like this eg. in index.blade.php

```
<div id="main" data-user_name="{{$user->name}}" />
```

Then in Main.js

```
const Main = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Component {...props} />
   </div>
 );
}

if(document.getElementById('main')) {
  const el = document.getElementById('main')
  const props = Object.assign({}, el.dataset)
  ReactDOM.render(<Main {...props} />, el);
}
```

Comment: how do we can init the user prop with the entire user object?

Answer (score 7):

This is perhaps a slightly cleaner solution than the others suggested. We don't need to specify each prop we pass in using this method either.

**In your blade file:**

```
<div id="react-component" data-foo='{{ $foo }}' data-bar='{{ $bar }}'>
```

On a side note, if `$foo` is something that isn't JSON, e.g a Laravel Collection or an array, we can apply an additional method: `$foo->toJson()`.

**In your component:**

```
if (document.getElementById('react-component')) {

    const component = document.getElementById('react-component');
    const props = Object.assign({}, component.dataset);

    ReactDOM.render(<ReactComponent {...props} />, component);
}
```

You'll then have access to all the props you pass in using the data attribute from your html. Just like any other react you can access your props inside of your component like: `this.props.foo`

Comment: Did you check by assigning the user as `data-user`. I mean an object. I guess we need to `JSON.parse` the string before assigning prop to component

Comment: @SachinKumar You'd have to cast the user object to an array, then JSON encode it `json_encode($user->toArray())` and then `JSON.parse` as you say to have access with the JS.

Comment: Can we use @json function provided by Laravel blade system?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this..

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('script')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ReactDOM.render(<Example name="{{ $user->name }}"/>, document.getElementById('example'));
    </script>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div id="example"></div>
@endsection
```

But better solution would be AJAX request to some controller that returns json data.

Best solution for you will this laravel package 
[laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer)

Comment: How can I use that json data then in my blade view or React components?

Comment: There are two options for passing PHP variables to JS.

1. Load controller url from JS that returns data in some format like xml, json and parse them to js variable

2. Insert inline javascript to blade view with needed data from php




`<script type="text/javascript">
       var awesomeString = "{{ $myString }}";
       var prettyObject = JSON.parse("{{ json_encode($likedObject) }}");
</script>`

Comment: how do I parse my data to a js variable and how can I use that data in a React component for example?

Comment: You need to define js variable somewhere inside your blade view. For example look at this js line `var userName = "{{ $user->name }}";`. That line define js variable with username in value. PHP simply replace **{{ $user->name }}** to user name. Result will be for example `var userName = "John";`. Then you can use userName variable everywhere in javascript. You can pass that variable to your react component or use it directly in any component.

Comment: This laravel package is very useful for passing PHP variables from your controller to JS. [https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer)