# How to update DOM after on axios return React JS and Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel-5, axios

I want to update my entire dashboard when select date as like as the attached image[image]

After select the date the entire page info will be updated. I am using React JS and axios to pick the date and Laravel to process the result and returning all arrays. But I am unsure how to embed the return results in the view (Blade).

**Dashboard Blade:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto" id='select-date'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='dashboard-content'>
        .....
    </div>
</div>
```

**Select Date:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class SelectDate extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            value: ''
        }
    }

    selectDate(e) {
        let url = window.location.href
        let date = e.target.value
        this.setState({value: date})
        axios.get(url+ '/' +date).then(response => {
            alert(response.data)
            document.getElementById('dashboard_content').innerHTML = response.data
        }).catch(error => {
            alert(error)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <select className="custom-select custom-select-sm" onChange={this.selectDate.bind(this)} value={this.state.value}>
                    <option selected value='7'>Last Week</option>
                    <option value="1">Today</option>
                    <option value="30">Last Month</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('select-date')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<SelectDate />, document.getElementById('select-date'));
}
```

Comment: Does this answer you question? [Laravel 5.5 render a React component in a blade view with data from the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47634287/laravel-5-5-render-a-react-component-in-a-blade-view-with-data-from-the-controll)

Answer (score 0):

When using React, the rule of thumb is not to manipulate the DOM yourself.
You need to use states, and for example, when you received the data with axios, you will update the state and then a re-render process will be triggered; your DOM will be updated according to the new state.

It's now clear what the backend (Laravel) returns, but if it's raw HTML code, it's not practical to use it with React. Instead, it's more practical that your backend would respond with some JSON data that you would update your UI according to it.